# Integration of $\int_{r}^{1}\rho^{2(1-\rho)}d\rho$

Tags: integration

I am trying to understand the solution of the following question:

> For every $p>0$ and for every $0<r<1$, evaluate the integral
>   $$I(r,p)=\iiint_{D_r}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p}dxdydz$$
>   Where $D$ is the space between a sphere in the center with radius $r$ and a sphere in the center with a radius of $1$. $$D_{r}=\{(x,y,z)\mid r^2\leq (x^2+y^2+z^2)^p\leq 1 \}$$

Solution:
$$I(r,p)
=
\iiint_{D_r}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p}dxdydz
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{r}^{1}\frac{1}{\rho^{2p}}\cdot \rho^2\sin(\varphi)d\rho d\varphi d\theta
=
2\pi\bigg(\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\varphi)d\varphi\bigg)\bigg(\int_{r}^{1}\rho^{2(1-p)}d\rho\bigg)
=
\frac{4\pi}{3-2p}(1-r^{3-2p}), p\neq\frac{2}{3}$$

My question is about the last integration, where
$$\small(1)\int_{r}^{1}\rho^{2(1-p)}d\rho=\frac{1}{3-2p}(1-r^{3-2p})$$

Can someone explain or rather show the steps on the integration of $\small(1)$?

Comment: I fear you may be mixing up the variables $p$ "p" and $\rho$ "rho". It may be a bad idea to introduce a variable $\rho$ when you already have a variable $p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Completely agree and this is particularly a bad idea for beginners who are just learning how to do rote calculations. Students with some theoretical background would generally be more capable of spotting a careless error like this. Its clear rho is the variable here and p is taken as a real parameter that takes specified constant values during the integration.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Indeed, I just noticed that it was a $p$ and not a $\rho$ in the last integration. I feel bad for spending two hours on such a silly mistake.

Comment: Note also that the question in the title uses $\rho$ instead of $p$.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the standard power rule $$ \int x^a dx = \frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}+ C$$ for $a\ne -1.$

In definite integral form: $$ \int_b^c x^adx = \frac{1}{a+1}(c^{a+1}-b^{a+1}).$$